# Remove inner polygons postgis

Tags: postgis, sql

I'm trying to remove inner polygons with postgis.
I've created a routine, that resumes in:

From a polygon table, with a unique id:

- Create a linestring table from polygon
- Import to postgis
- Get the length of each line

Now I have a table with, for example, 5 linestrings for each id, each linestring was a polygon, and I want to get ONLY the longest line from each ID.

[image]

For this, I have a select, but I don't know how to group the geometry, to get ONLY the longest line

```
select  id, geom as length from esp_lines group by id
```

I have to group it by another field, but I don't know which one.

The other solution I've found is:

```
select  id, max(geom) as length from esp_lines group by id
```

but max(geom) doesn't give me the expected result (the longest linestring)

Does anybody know if is there any function to get the longest linestring of a group?

Comment: there is no guarantee that the longest line would be the outer line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [Exterior ring](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html)

```
SELECT gid, ST_ExteriorRing(the_geom) AS ering
FROM sometable;
```

Comment: ST_ExteriorRing(the_geom) works only on POLYGONs. We need a solution working on MULTIPOLYGONs...

Answer (score 0):

The ST_ExteriorRing returns a linestring.  Use ST_MakePolygon to return a polygon that represents the original polygon with the donut holes removed.

```
SELECT gid, ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(the_geom)) AS ering
FROM sometable;
```

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html

Also be careful that sometable does not contain Multipolygons.
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html